# How do I assume faction leadership?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4, man-the-guns

In the new Hearts of Iron 4 expansion, man the guns, it should be possible to  take over leadership of a faction.

What are the conditions that need to be met to be able to do this, and how do you this as the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the screenshot. It's a diplomatic interaction with the faction leader. The exact amount of deployed manpower and factories depends on the faction leader's power.

[image: assume direct control]